# Girsanov theorem and change of measure

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Under the risk neutral measure Q, the stock price S follows a process $dS_t=rS_t dt+ σS_t dW_t^Q$, $W_t^Q$ is a standard brownian motion. Another measure is introduced with which I am not familiar that is $Q^{S}$, so that:
$dQ^S/dQ= S(T)/E^Q [S(T)]$. The right term is $Z(t)$ in the Girsanov theorem.
  My question is how do we prove that under $Q^S$, the process $W_t^{Q^S}= W_t^Q- σt$ is a martingale.

Comment: You may want to try quant.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the answer by myself. Under the risk neutral probability measure Q, $E^{Q}[S(T)] = e^{r}$, so that $Z(t)= e^{(µ-r- σ^2/2)t+ σW_t}= e^{- σ^2/2 t+ σW_t^Q}$.
   Now we know how $Z(t)$ looks like so using the  Girsanov theorem $W_t^{Q^S}= W_t^Q- σt$ is a brownian motion under $Q^{S}$.